# Scatter gather routing error. Message payload is of type: String

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm new to Mule and while working on a fairly simple Hello World example on Anypoint Studio to test out the Scatter/Gather flow control element, I'm getting the following error, without much else in the way of information:

```
ERROR 2014-12-19 22:00:30,172 [[unifinesb].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message : Exception was found for route(s): 0. Message payload is of type: String
Type : org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException
Code : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/routing/CompositeRoutingException.html
Payload : /Waldo
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Exception was found for route(s): 0. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException)
org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy:51 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/routing/CompositeRoutingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.routing.CompositeRoutingException: Exception was found for route(s): 0. Message payload is of type: String
at org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy.aggregateWithFailedRoutes(CollectAllAggregationStrategy.java:51)
at org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy.aggregate(CollectAllAggregationStrategy.java:38)
at org.mule.routing.ScatterGatherRouter.processResponses(ScatterGatherRouter.java:207)
at org.mule.routing.ScatterGatherRouter.process(ScatterGatherRouter.java:135)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at ...
```

Judging from the top description of the error, I understand the problem to be that Scatter gather does not receive String payloads, even though the current documentation for the component mentions nothing of the sort. Is this correct?

The flow I'm running is fairly simple, receiving a String from an inbound http and trying to route it to a REST service that will use the String to print something (returning text/plain) and to a DB to store the String in a table. Relevant code follows:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8084" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<expression-filter expression="#[payload != '/favicon.ico']" doc:name="Filter browser icon padding"/>
<logger message="current payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Startup log - to stdout"/>
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
<processor-chain>
<logger message="#['Rest branch msg input :' + payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="File Logger"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:8080/application/rest/mensaje?givenName=#[payload]" doc:name="REST Service"/>
<logger message="#['Rest msg output :' + payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="File Logger"/>
</processor-chain>
<processor-chain>
<logger message="#['Database msg input :' + payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="File Logger"/>
<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_VestaLocal" doc:name="Application Postgress">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into http_user_info (first_name) values ('#[payload]');]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:insert>
<logger message="#['Database msg output :' + payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="File Logger"/>
</processor-chain>
</scatter-gather>
<set-payload value="#['REST DB Success!']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Trawling through the net I found this old Mule JIRA issue with an exception similar to what I'm getting, but trying out the suggested solution (workaround?) didn't do anything for me: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7594

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something wrong is happening in your route 0.

You are getting a composite routing exception as per documentation:

> The CompositeRoutingException is new to the 3.5.0 Runtime. It extends
>   the Mule MessagingException to aggregate exceptions from different
>   routes in the context of a single message router. Exceptions are
>   correlated to each route through a sequential ID.
>
> This exception exposes two methods which allow you to obtain the IDs
>   of failed routes and the exceptions returned by each route.
>
> The getExceptions method returns a map where the key is an integer
>   that identifies the index of the failed route, and the value is the
>   exception itself. The getExceptionForRouteIndex(int) method returns
>   the exception of the requested route ID.

As you don't have an execption strategy, the toString is call to that exception and that only prints the route failing (that has nothing to do with the fact that the payload is String)

Please use the following exeption strategy to find out exactly what's wrong:

```
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
    <logger level="ERROR" message="#[exception.exceptions]"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the small detail with the exception logging. After placing the catch you suggested, additional information showed that the REST service I was invoking did not implement a POST method - and I hadn't noticed POST is the default for Mule http connector.